# Conditional statements on time series data python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series, conditional-statements

I'm trying to execute conditional statements on time series data. Is there a way to set the "t_value" to zero if the time is between 1) 00:00:00 and 02:00:00  2) 04:00:00 & 06:00:00

```
                   t_value
2019-11-24 00:00:00  4.0
2019-11-24 01:00:00  7.8
2019-11-24 02:00:00  95.1
2019-11-24 03:00:00  78.4
2019-11-24 04:00:00  8.0
2019-11-24 05:00:00  17.50
2019-11-24 06:00:00  55.00
2019-11-24 07:00:00  66.00
2019-11-25 00:00:00  21.00
2019-11-25 01:00:00  12.40
```

`if-else` & `np.where` are probable options but I'm unsure on how to implement the conditions on hours.

Comment: so in your example only 7am would have a value?

Comment: Yes, but this is only an example. I’ll edit it to a more suitable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use **[between_time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html)** to get the datetimes between the specified times, then use **[loc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html)** to assign the new values :

I'll use @Ben.T's sample data :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'t_value':range(1,11)}, 
              index=pd.date_range('2020-05-17 00:00:00', periods=10, freq='1H'))

#get the time indices for the different ranges
m1 = df.between_time('00:00:00','02:00:00').index
m2 = df.between_time('04:00:00','06:00:00').index

#assign 0 to the t_value column matches : 
df.loc[m1|m2] = 0

print(df)

            t_value
2020-05-17 00:00:00 0
2020-05-17 01:00:00 0
2020-05-17 02:00:00 0
2020-05-17 03:00:00 4
2020-05-17 04:00:00 0
2020-05-17 05:00:00 0
2020-05-17 06:00:00 0
2020-05-17 07:00:00 8
2020-05-17 08:00:00 9
2020-05-17 09:00:00 10
```

Comment: what if I want to use the time range (00:00:00,03:00:00) and t_value>0 to calculate a new column which classifies them as correct(>0) & incorrect(=0)?

Comment: off the back of my head, sounds like sth u can put into ```loc```, with the ```m1|m2``` part  . u could edit ur question for the addition, although it is much better to ask a new question altogether

Comment: Posted a new question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61869990/using-time-and-numerical-value-in-conditional-statements-to-create-categorical-c 

If you want to give it a try

Answer (score 1):

you can acces the time from your datetime index with `time` and create mask depending on your condition. Then use `loc` and `|` to concatenate your mask as or.

```
#sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'t_value':range(1,11)}, 
              index=pd.date_range('2020-05-17 00:00:00', periods=10, freq='1H'))

# masks
m1 = ((df.index.time>=pd.to_datetime('00:00:00').time()) 
      & (df.index.time<=pd.to_datetime('02:00:00').time()))
m2 = ((df.index.time>=pd.to_datetime('04:00:00').time())
      & (df.index.time<=pd.to_datetime('06:00:00').time()))

#set the value to 0
df.loc[m1|m2, 't_value'] = 0

print (df)
                     t_value
2020-05-17 00:00:00        0
2020-05-17 01:00:00        0
2020-05-17 02:00:00        0
2020-05-17 03:00:00        4
2020-05-17 04:00:00        0
2020-05-17 05:00:00        0
2020-05-17 06:00:00        0
2020-05-17 07:00:00        8
2020-05-17 08:00:00        9
2020-05-17 09:00:00       10
```