# Using time and numerical value in conditional statements to create categorical column python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, conditional-statements, categories

I'm trying to execute if statement using time and numerical value to make a new column categorical column

`Condition - if time is between 05:00:00 and 19:00:00 and t_value > 0 & t_value <=13 then classify as "C" else "IC"`

`If time is not in the range then classify as NA`

Example Input

```
                   t_value 
2020-05-17 00:00:00 0     
2020-05-17 01:00:00 0
2020-05-17 02:00:00 0
2020-05-17 03:00:00 0
2020-05-17 04:00:00 0
2020-05-17 05:00:00 0
2020-05-17 06:00:00 0
2020-05-17 07:00:00 8
2020-05-17 08:00:00 9
2020-05-17 09:00:00 10
2020-05-17 10:00:00 11
2020-05-17 11:00:00 12
```

I'm unsure of the approach to take in this regard

Expected Output

```
                t_value  C/IC
2020-05-17 00:00:00 0    NA
2020-05-17 01:00:00 0    NA
2020-05-17 02:00:00 0    NA
2020-05-17 03:00:00 0    NA
2020-05-17 04:00:00 0    NA
2020-05-17 05:00:00 0    IC
2020-05-17 06:00:00 0    IC
2020-05-17 07:00:00 8    C
2020-05-17 08:00:00 9    C
2020-05-17 09:00:00 10   C
2020-05-17 10:00:00 11   C
2020-05-17 11:00:00 12   C
```

Comment: y is 9 am IC ? it should be C

Comment: Yes, edited the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#convert to datetime index
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

#get condition for time boundary
cond1 = df.between_time( '05:00:00', '19:00:00')

print(cond1.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2020-05-17 05:00:00', '2020-05-17 06:00:00',
               '2020-05-17 07:00:00', '2020-05-17 08:00:00',
               '2020-05-17 09:00:00', '2020-05-17 10:00:00',
               '2020-05-17 11:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

#get index to match the t_value conditions

#indices that match time boundary, but not t_value boundary
ic = cond1.loc[~(cond1.t_value.gt(0)) & (cond1.t_value.le(13))].index

#indices that match time boundary and t_value boundary
c = cond1.loc[(cond1.t_value.gt(0)) & (cond1.t_value.le(13))].index

#assign value
df.loc[c,'C/IC'] = "C"
df.loc[ic,'C/IC'] = "IC"

print(df)

    t_value C/IC
2020-05-17 00:00:00 0   NaN
2020-05-17 01:00:00 0   NaN
2020-05-17 02:00:00 0   NaN
2020-05-17 03:00:00 0   NaN
2020-05-17 04:00:00 0   NaN
2020-05-17 05:00:00 0   IC
2020-05-17 06:00:00 0   IC
2020-05-17 07:00:00 8   C
2020-05-17 08:00:00 9   C
2020-05-17 09:00:00 10  C
2020-05-17 10:00:00 11  C
2020-05-17 11:00:00 12  C
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Care to try another? Here I've been trying to remove the date (all the time blocks) if the incorrect value count is greater than 2 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61862447/drop-dates-based-on-condition-in-python/61862761#61862761